C# ConvNetSharp API - Question about an example (Classify2DDemo)
I am working on my data according to the example (Classify2DDemo) given below:
https://github.com/cbovar/ConvNetSharp/blob/master/Examples/Classify2DDemo/Program.cs
The example initializes the hotLabels as per the statement below:

var hotLabels = BuilderInstance.Volume.SameAs(new Shape(1, 1, 2, n));

The example code works properly, however do we need 2 * n blocks of memory to store the integer labels OR 1 * n is sufficient? Should the Shape be like below?

var hotLabels = BuilderInstance.Volume.SameAs(new Shape(1, 1, 1, n));

